# Question on FIR filter

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

I've been trying to do this problem for the last few hours. Could someone show me the workings on how it is done? Not just the answer.

[image]

The figure shows the structure of a FIR filter where $A = 1.5$, $B = 0.69$ and $C = 3.0$.

If $x[n] = u[n]$, what is the value of $y[n]$ for $n = 20$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED] From left to right, try to find the impulse response. On the bottom branch, delay the unit pulse $d$ and get $d[n-1]$. Add $Ad[n]$. Delay twice and get $d[n-3] +Ad[n-2]$. Add $Bd[n]$. Add $Cd[n-1]$. So the FIR coefficients of the impulse response $h$ will be $[1,A,C,B]$, but in the reverse order (as correctly pointed out by colleagues), because $y[n] = \sum d[k]h[n-k]$. So your system is causal, and $h[0]=B$, $h[1]=C$, $h[2]=A$, $h[3]=1$.

However, at $n=20$, you are in a stabilized region of the signal (all the known samples are equal to $1$, so even if you make a mistake as I did first, the answer will be the same, $1+A+C+B$, as stated before by other colleagues.

Comment: What's D and where did B go?!?! ;-)

Comment: could you detail the steps a bit more? I'm still a bit confused on the process.

Comment: @Peter K. My first try on a smartphone is clumsy. Thx

Comment: @sky knight can you try to tell us where you are stuck? Imagine you push a 1 into the input. What happens after each block?

Comment: My reading of the block diagram says $[B,C,A,1]$. Though perhaps I'm doing the reverse of yours?

Comment: alright so the first 3 terms i got was
y[0] = 1xB
y[1] = 1xB + 1xC
y[2] = 1 + 1xB + 1xC
The process i used was following the path and the time delay so that the max time delay doesn't exceed n.

Comment: oh i think i made a mistake in y[3] = 1xA + 1xB + 1xC. so that means its [B,C,A,1] is it? Also would that make y[20] = 6.19?

Comment: @Peter K. Probably I was doing the reverse of yours, incorrectly

Comment: Hope you don't mind me editing, just some unfortunate typos ...

Comment: @Matt L. of course not, consequences of answering half asleep, and edited half-awake. My apologies

Answer (score 2):

If you start from the left, you have:

[image]

So if you want to calculate $y[20]$ when $x[n]=u[n]$, then you have to just replace these expressions in the general form of $y[n]$:

$$y[n] = B x[n] + C x[n-1] + A x[n-2] + x[n-3]$$
$$y[20] = B u[20] + C u[19] + A u[18] + u[17]$$
$$y[20] = B+C+A+1=6.19$$

Comment: How did you produce the graph?

Comment: @LaurentDuval using Paint.

Answer (score 1):

Ok may be this simplified explanation fits:

1- if the input of a delay is x[n] then its output is x[n-1].

2- when there are k delays in series then it will be x[n-k].

3- based on 1 and 2, and following the signal paths: sum up all the signals:
 $$y[n] = B x[n] + C x[n-1] + A x[n-2] + x[n-3]$$

Now if x[n] = u[n], then by its very popular property of being = 1 for n>=0, all input values will be 1 for n>=3. Hence y[n] = A+B+C+1 = 6.19 for all n>=2.